# Complex Geometric Interpretation of Mordell conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves

The Mordell conjecture/Falting's Theorem says that any smooth projective curve $X$ of genus $g\geq 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has finitely many integer points (using the valuatlive criterion).

We can of course apply the analytification functor then the sturcture morphism of $X$ becomes
$$X(\mathbb{C})^{an}\rightarrow \text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})(\mathbb{C})^{an}$$
and an integer point corresponds to a section of this morphism. However $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})(\mathbb{C})^{an}$ is just a point, so this is not an interesting geometric object. However, on an intuitive level, the specta of Dedekind domains correspond to $1$-dimensional curves.

My question therefore is if there exists a (complex) geometric interpretation of the Mordell Conjecture?

The most naive interpretation I have and can thus hope for this would be that there exist only finitely many maps
$$\mathbb{C}\rightarrow X(\mathbb{C})^{an}.$$
Is there anything in that direction?

Comment: it's true that there are finitely many maps from $\mathbb{C}$ to a closed Riemann surface of genus $g\geq 2$. Have you read about the Mordell conjecture over function fields?

Comment: @crispr Yes, I'm aware of the function field analogy and the Mordell conjecture in that setting.

Comment: I guess my question could be clarified by asking "What is the complex analogue of a integer point?"

Comment: possibly something like this https://mathoverflow.net/q/52419